# What is the value of $\int e^{t^2/2}(t^2+1)dt$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I've been trying to evaluate $\int e^{t^2/2}(t^2+1)dt$ by IBP or substitution but I either fall in a tautology or something non-elementary, or keep going ad infinitum. What am I missing?

Comment: differentiate $$e^{t^2/2}\cdot t$$ with respect to $t$

Comment: @Sonnhard: Yes, I know. But I wouldn't have guessed it, how to evaluate the integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first separate to get it as $\int e^{t^2/2}t^2 +\int e^{t^2} $ . Now just integrate by part the second term and the first term automatically vanishes.

Comment: Ohh you mean to integrate by parts $1\cdot e^{t^2/2}$, right thank you!